# Editing a snippet in a package in Atom

Tags: package, atom-editor, code-snippets

In Atom, if a package contains snippets, how do you edit them or delete/deactivate some whilst keeping the rest?

I know I can disable the snippets and copy them into Atom->File->Snippets. However, I think that these snippets would exist for all languages whereas packages like `languages-html` and `languages-latex` only activate snippets when their respective language is being used. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippets defined in `snippets.cson` take precedence over all snippets provided by packages, because they are loaded later. You can copy & paste the snippets you want to edit to that file and make your edits. Snippets will be limited to the language grammar you specify in the top-level property.

**Example**

```coffee
'.source.js':
  'console.log':
    'prefix': 'log'
    'body': 'Unexpectedly, this does not expand to console.log'
```

This will override the default snippet, which expands `log` to `console.log`